# MATLAB Set image size

Tags: image, matlab, plot, image-size

I have a code that is creating and capturing a jpg file. However, it tends to come out with two different image sizes. This becomes a problem when I want to make the jpg files into a movie. I have set `PaperPosition` and a few other things as well, but it still comes out with two image sizes. The image size change seems random since if I run the code twice, an image that had one of the sizes before could have the other size now.

```
nFrames = 8797; % Number of frames. Number of days between 1/1/1990 and 1/31/2014
for k = 1:nFrames % 1/1/1990 to the number of days.
    % Map of conterminous US
    ax = figure(1);
    set(ax, 'visible', 'off', 'units','normalized','outerposition',[0 0 1 1]); %  Make window that shows up full sized, which makes saved figure clearer
    ax = usamap('conus');
    states = shaperead('usastatelo', 'UseGeoCoords', true,...
        'Selector',...
        {@(name) ~any(strcmp(name,{'Alaska','Hawaii'})), 'Name'});
    faceColors = makesymbolspec('Polygon',...
        {'INDEX', [1 numel(states)], 'FaceColor', 'none'}); % NOTE - colors are random
    geoshow(ax, states, 'DisplayType', 'polygon', ...
        'SymbolSpec', faceColors)
    framem off; gridm off; mlabel off; plabel off

    hold on

    % Plot data
    scatterm(ax,str2double(Lat_O3{k}), str2double(Lon_O3{k}), 40, str2double(data_O3{k})*1000, 'filled'); % Plot a dot at each Lat and Lon
    hold on

    % Colorbar
    caxis([10 90]);
    h = colorbar;
    ylabel(h,'ppb');

    % Title
    % date = datenum(2007, 04, 29) + k; % Convert t into serial numbers.
    title(['O3 MDA8 Concentration ', datestr(cell2mat(date_O3(k)), 'mmm dd yyyy')]); % Title changes every daytitle(str);

    % Capture the frame
    mov(k) = getframe(gcf); % Makes figure window pop up

    % Set size of image
    set(gcf,'Units','points')
    set(gcf,'PaperUnits','points')

    size = get(gcf,'Position');
    size = size(3:4);
    set(gcf,'PaperSize',size)

    set(gcf,'PaperPosition',[0,0,size(1),size(2)])

    % Save as jpg (just specify other format as necessary) - Must set 'facecolor' to 'none' or else color of states turn out black
    eval(['print -djpeg map_US_' datestr(cell2mat(date_O3(k)),'yyyy_mm_dd') '_O3_MDA8.jpg']);
    % saveas(gca, ['WI_' datestr(cell2mat(Date)) '_PM25.jpg']);
    clf

end

% Save as AVI file - Set 'facecolor' to 'white'. It looks better.
close(gcf)
```

How can I set the image size (hopefully to full screen like I tried to do in `set(ax, ...)` so that when I save the jpg files, they are all the same size?

Comment: I have had some success using `subplot('position',[0 0 1 1]);` which basically plots "in the full window". Also - it is possible that the size changes if the contents of axis labels etc. changes. Did you try to plot with all axes off?

Comment: Where did you place the `subplot` command? I don't have `axes` `on` do I? Where?

Comment: I place `subplot` after creating a figure, and before creating a plot: `figure; subplot('position',[0 0 1 1]); plot(X, Y); axes off;` . I admit to not being familiar with the geo plotting routines so this may not apply in your case. Hard to reproduce your problem without pictures or data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply resize the image to whatever size you want, so you know it will be constant.

```
B = imresize(A, [numrows numcols])
```

Look at the [imresize](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imresize.html) documentation if you have other particular questions about it.

Comment: I am not sure whether the problem is in the number of data points in the image, or in the way the plot appears on the screen...

Comment: Neither am I, but if the above code is implemented and it is still generating odd image size, then we know it is not that.

Comment: just casting out a line, seeing if something bites :)

Comment: I think that OP is using `scatterm` which is a funny kind of "geographical scatter plot". As such I'm not sure what `A` would be in his case.

Comment: @Floris True. But what could be done is resizing the handle it output. Maybe something like `h = scatterm(..), set(h,'Position',[50,50,10,100])`